# docker: ngnix always stops when CMD is executed in dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, dockerfile

I try to setup a docker container which runs ngnix and nodejs at the same time.

my dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM nginx:mainline-alpine
RUN apk add  --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main/ nodejs=12.14.0-r0
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN apk add --no-cache nano

ADD ./myHelloWorld /myHelloWorld


CMD ["node", "/myHelloWorld/index.js"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

The base docker image has the command for starting ngnix
But ngnix is not running after starting my container. when i remove the CMD line in my docker file which starts nodejs. nginx works as expected.

i tried a lot, and everytime when i have an CMD in my dockerfile, ngnix is not running.
i read that ngnix needs the parameter "-g", "daemon off;"   But my base image is starting nginx exactly in this way. https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/stable/alpine/Dockerfile

if i add

```
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

at the end of MY Dockerfile (which doesn't make sense, because it's already part of the base image), then ngnix is running, but the nodejs is not running any more.

does someone have an idea how to run both: ngnix and nodejs?

I would be very grateful

Kind Regards
Stefan

Comment: Standard practice is to run these in two separate containers.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple `CMD` instructions. You can write a shell script that starts both `nginx` and `node` and run the shell script as part of `CMD` instruction.

This is not recommended though. As mentioned in the documentation:

> It is generally recommended that you separate areas of concern by
>   using one service per container. That service may fork into multiple
>   processes.

. You should run your nginx and node app in different containers. You can connect them using shared networks and volumes if required. Checkout [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) which makes the job of starting multiple containers easy. If you still want multiple services in a single container, a better approach would be to use a process manager like `supervisord`.

See - https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i need nginx and nodejs in the same container. nginx is used as reversed proxy. 

i already tried it with a shell script which has just this two lines: 

bash /etc/init.d/nginx -g "daemon off;"
node /myHelloWorld/index.js


but after starting the container, again only nodejs is running.

Comment: okay, i was able to write a script which is working. 

node /myHelloWorld/index.js &
cd /etc/init.d
nginx -g "daemon off;"

thanks for your tipps!

Answer (score 0):

A docker image can only have one `CMD`. If you include multiple `CMD`s, the last one will take effect ([documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)). The Dockerfile for the base image has `CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]`, which means it will start `nginx`. When you include a `CMD` in your Dockerfile to run `node`, you are overwriting the original `CMD`, and `nginx` will not run by default.

You can run `nginx` and `node` separately using the same image.

```
docker run MYIMAGE node /myHelloWorld/index.js
docker run MYIMAGE nginx -g "daemon off;"
```